# Как вывести на страницу только одно значение из результата post запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

В ответе из ajax запроса получаю такой резултат [{"msisdn":"999999999","debug_opt":false,"service":"prepaid"}]
Как вывести только одно значение например "service": "prepaid" в читабельном виде.
Сам скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#enter').click(function(){
        var input = document.getElementById('numid');
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://177.77.44.999:8081/spgw/v1',
            xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
      },
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "method": "subscriberInfo",
          "params":[{"msisdn": input.value}],
          "id":"1"
        }),
             success: function(msg){
                                var data = JSON.stringify(msg.result);
                                    $('#RoumInfo').html('<ul>Сведения по 
                  абоненту: ' + data + '</ul>');
          },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('POST failed.' + JSON.stringify(responseData));
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
          });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку в ответе от сервера у вас массив с объектом, то надо делать так.

```
success: function(msg){
     var resp = msg.result[0] // Получаем первый элмент массива.
     if(resp) // Здесь проверяем, есть ли первый элемент
       $('#RoumInfo').html('<ul>Сведения по абоненту: ' + resp.service + '</ul>'); // Здесь берем свойство service
     else
       $('#RoumInfo').html('<ul>Сведения по абоненту: Не найдены</ul>'); // Если сервер не нашел значений
},
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё отлично работает!

Comment: @Aldem Если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, выделите его как верный.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй:

```
success: function(msg) {                                   
    $('#RoumInfo').html('<ul>Сведения по 
        абоненту: ' + msg['service'] + '</ul>');
     },
```

или

```
msg.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно делать `JSON.stringfy()` сделай например так:

```
success: function(msg){
    const resService = msg.result.service; // выводиться ниже.
    const resMsi = msg.result.msisdn; // куда то ещё можно вставить ниже.
    const resDebugOpt = msg.result.debug_opt; // куда то ещё можно вставить ниже.
    $('#RoumInfo').html('<ul>Сведения по абоненту: ' + resService + '</ul>');
},
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за оперативную помощь.

Comment: Обращайся если что, и выбери верный ответ ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#enter').click(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('numid');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://177.77.44.999:8081/spgw/v1',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: false
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "method": "subscriberInfo",
      "params": [{
        "msisdn": input.value
      }],
      "id": "1"
    }),
    success: function(msg) {
      try {
        var msgJson = JSON.parse(msg);
      } catch (e) {
              alert('Error.Please refresh the page!');
      }

      $('#RoumInfo').html('<ul>Сведения по  абоненту: ' + msgJson.service + '</ul>');
    },
    error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('POST failed.' + JSON.stringify(responseData));
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  });
});
```